# Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin' for kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kapt

I am trying to build my app, while building the app, I got the below error,

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

I trued different solutions such as, Removing `.gradle` and `.idea` of the app and tried to rebuild the app

Added

```
// Hilt
def hilt_version = "2.45"
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"

// Inject WorkManager with Hilt
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0'
kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"


// Kotlin Coroutines
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.1"
// Firebase Coroutines
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.6.1'

kapt 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.4.2'
```

But nothing works for me.

Here is the log after doing `Run with --stacktrace`.

```
        Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
        > A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
           > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
        
        * Try:
        > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
        > Run with --scan to get full insights.
        
        * Exception is:
        org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147)
            at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:145)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:133)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
            at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:333)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:320)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:313)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:299)
            at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:143)
            at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:227)
            at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:218)
            at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:140)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
            at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkItemExecution.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:339)
            at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.lambda$waitForItemsAndGatherFailures$2(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:131)
            at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
            at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:341)
            at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:326)
            at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:127)
            at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:93)
            at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForAll(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:79)
            at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForCompletion(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:67)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:250)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:227)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:210)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:193)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:171)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:89)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:40)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:53)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:50)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:50)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:40)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:68)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:38)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:36)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:29)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:61)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:42)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:60)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:27)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:180)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:75)
            at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:73)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:48)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:110)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:73)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:44)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:89)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:50)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:114)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:57)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:76)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:50)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNoEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:249)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:86)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:54)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:43)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:31)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:287)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:44)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:33)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:76)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:144)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:133)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
            at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:333)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:320)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:313)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:299)
            at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:143)
            at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:227)
            at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:218)
            at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:140)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution.run(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:316)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction.execute(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:262)
            at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
            at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
            at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
            at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
            at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
            at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
            at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
            at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
            at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
            at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:205)
            at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)
            at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
            at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
            at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
            at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:270)
            at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:119)
            at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:124)
            at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)
            at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
            ... 2 more
        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:90)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:31)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:47)
            ... 34 more
        Caused by: com.sun.tools.javac.processing.AnnotationProcessingError: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: failure, see logs for details.
        Exception while handling step android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions@332d6c6 javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
         - with linked exception:
        [org.apache.xerces.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.]
            at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:308)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:548)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:234)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:199)
            at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:140)
            at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:179)
            at android.databinding.tool.store.ResourceBundle$LayoutFileBundle.fromXML(ResourceBundle.java:941)
            at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions$IntermediateV2.appendTo(ProcessExpressions.java:348)
            at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions.onHandleStep(ProcessExpressions.java:121)
            at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.runStep(ProcessDataBinding.java:246)
            at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.access$000(ProcessDataBinding.java:231)
            at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.doProcess(ProcessDataBinding.java:112)
            at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.process(ProcessDataBinding.java:87)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalProcessor.process(incrementalProcessors.kt:90)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:197)
            at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1023)
            at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:939)
            at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1267)
            at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1382)
            at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1234)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:90)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:31)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:47)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at 
   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
        Caused by: org.apache.xerces.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.scanLiteral(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.scanAttributeValue(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:228)
            ... 65 more
```

Comment: Did you added in root gradle too?
classpath("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.48")

Comment: @pseudoankit I have  classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.45' on my root gradle